# I need some help against the money mis in sha256

Tags: key, sha256, bitcoin, ecdsa

Having a private ECDSA key 18E14A7B6A307F426A94F8114701E7C8E774E7F9A47E2C2035DB29A206321725

1 - Take the corresponding public key generated with it 0450863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A299FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6

2 - Perform SHA-256 hashing on the public key 600FFE422B4E00731A59557A5CCA46CC183944191006324A447BDB2D98D4B408

but when I run a sha256 on 0450863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A299FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6

I don't get

600FFE422B4E00731A59557A5CCA46CC183944191006324A447BDB2D98D4B408

What I get is

32511e82d56dcea68eb774094e25bab0f8bdd9bc1eca1ceeda38c7a43aceddce

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to:

- Hash with `SHA-256` the public key: `0450863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A299FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6`
- Hash with `RIPEMD-160` the key: `600FFE422B4E00731A59557A5CCA46CC183944191006324A447BDB2D98D4B408`

Which should result in `010966776006953D5567439E5E39F86A0D273BEE`.

[image]

Comment: I will show you more This is a public key 0450863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A2‌​99FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6 When I try to Perform SHA-256 hashing on the public key I do not get 600FFE422B4E00731A59557A5CCA46CC183944191006324A447BDB2D98D4B408 But get 32511e82d56dcea68eb774094e25bab0f8bdd9bc1eca1ceeda38c7a43aceddce Please could you tell me what is the mis here

Comment: The problem is that you are hashing the hexadecimal/ascii and not the binary representation of the public key. Run this: `echo "0450863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A299FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6"
| xxd -r -p /proc/self/fd/0 | sha256sum` and you will get `600FFE422B4E00731A59557A5CCA46CC183944191006324A447BDB2D98D4B408`.

Comment: You are a genius I beg Can you give me an explanation of the process How to do it I want to see a picture or something I want to understand in order to get a correct value and I appreciate your help

Comment: I'm not even close to a genius. You need a linux terminal to execute the above command. If you don't have one available, go to: http://www.compileonline.com/execute_bash_online.php and execute the command I wrote you in my previous comment. Make sure you remove any added (by the copy/paste process) spaces. I also added a screenshot to my answer.

Comment: Thank you dear friend to help me and I need you to work with me and I will pay you money for your work with me will need to encrypt and decrypt some things and see some of the Omer and I will pay you This is my e-mail in order to chat with you in the business details vcardbuy@gmail.com or kem50@yahoo.com and e_@hotmail.com

Comment: Also have a simple question my friend a simple question if i want to decompress this hash 600FFE422B4E00731A59557A5CCA46CC183944191006324A447BDB2D98D4B408  Through this site http://www.compileonline.com/execute_bash_online.php What do I do, what is decompressed؟

Comment: @kem this is a SHA-256 hash, what do you mean by "decompress" it?

Comment: This is the hash SHA-256 600FFE422B4E00731A59557A5CCA46CC183944191006324A447BDB2D98D4B408 How can decode his work What is something that must be written here http://www.compileonline.com/execute_bash_online.php

Comment: @kem SHA-256 is a cryptographic hashing algorithm. That means it is a one-way hashing algorithm, so it cannot be decoded and that's the whole meaning behind it. You can try to brute-force it but it could take more ages to decrypt it than it took this universe to come together as one piece.

Comment: My friend I wrote this for the encryption | xxd -r -p /proc/self/fd/0 | sha256sum Is there something similar in order to decrypt؟

Comment: @kem you cannot decrypt it. It's not possible.

Comment: I have another question my friend How can create address bitcoin An example of this 1bonesEeTcABPjLzAb1VkFgySY6Zqu3sX ؟؟

Comment: @kem This is out of the context of this question so you had better open a new question on the board about it.

Comment: I opened a new Soil Can you answer now؟

Comment: @kem the guidelines are clear, you need to open a new question (and not to answer your latest question). Open a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: Creating the new tag 'card' requires at least 1500 reputation. Try something from the existing tags list instead.

Comment: I'm sorry to wasted your time my friend, but I have a company and I need this information too, and I appreciate the help i Having a private ECDSA key 18E14A7B6A307F426A94F8114701E7C8E774E7F9A47E2C2035DB29A206321725 How can encrypt to 0450863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A299FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6 and How can decrypt also

Comment: @kem what you're asking is very complicated to answer here, for the same reasons I described above. If you have a company you should hire a specialist to do these things for you, they require special skills and knowledge.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother but I want to answer one question only How to create Private key What consists

Comment: Please my friend when I'm trying to encrypt SHA-256 600FFE422B4E00731A59557A5CCA46CC183944191006324A447BDB2D98D4B408 to  RIPEMD-160 I do not get 010966776006953D5567439E5E39F86A0D273BEE But get 1435727e0369ab470035797c66215799f258188b Please tell me what to do in order to get the correct result here http://www.compileonline.com/execute_bash_online.php Is it -r -p /proc/self/fd/0 | ripemd-160sum Or what ؟

Comment: @kem I was going to answer to your question but then I realized you unaccepted my answer, which was correct, and this is totally unacceptable by the community standards.

Comment: No friend, I swear to you is I just mis-corrected everything now I hope that the response to my question please

Comment: And I apologize again for what went wrong and I wish I could help you Please my friend when I'm trying to encrypt SHA-256 600FFE422B4E00731A59557A5CCA46CC183944191006324A447BDB2D98D4B408 to RIPEMD-160 I do not get 010966776006953D5567439E5E39F86A0D273BEE But get 1435727e0369ab470035797c66215799f258188b Please tell me what to do in order to get the correct result here compileonline.com/execute_bash_online.php Is it -r -p /proc/self/fd/0 | ripemd-160sum Or what ؟

Comment: And I apologize again for what went wrong and I wish I could help you Please my friend when I'm trying to encrypt SHA-256 600FFE422B4E00731A59557A5CCA46CC183944191006324A447BDB2D98D4B408 to RIPEMD-160 I do not get 010966776006953D5567439E5E39F86A0D273BEE But get 1435727e0369ab470035797c66215799f258188b Please tell me what to do in order to get the correct result here compileonline.com/execute_bash_online.php Is it -r -p /proc/self/fd/0 | ripemd-160sum Or what